# TypeError in cordova_plugins.js

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

Whenever I create a project using the PhoneGap Desktop Application, I get this error in the console of index.html file for cordova_plugins.js:

```
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**
```

And when I open the cordova_plugins.js file in browser, it shows this -

```
****TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined at assertPath (path.js:7:11) at Object.join (path.js:506:7) at Object.handle (D:\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect-phonegap\lib\middleware\cordova\cordova_plugins.js:18:33) at next (D:\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15) at Object.handle (D:\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect-phonegap\lib\middleware\cordova\cordova.js:33:13) at next (D:\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15) at resume (D:\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:65:7) at SendStream.error (D:\PhoneGap Desktop\resources\app.asar\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:80:37) at emitOne (events.js:90:13) at SendStream.emit (events.js:182:7)****
```

The project is in `D:\Applications\samplApp.`
PhoneGap Desktop is install in `D:\PhoneGap Desktop`.

Please help me in fixing this. Maybe because of this, every external plugin I try to load, `window.plugins.plugin_name` in js results in error that window.plugins is undefined. If you need any other information, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the plugin to your app's folder.

```
cordova plugins add plugin_name
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am using the desktop application. There is no console sort of thing in it. To add plugins, we need to edit the config.xml file and phonegap injects the plugin itself. But as I said, there is this error for cordova_plugins.js, and maybe that's why the plugins do not load. But few plugins are added by default to the projects created using the desktop application, and they have their folders, they are not injected, and they are working.  Thanks, again.